# Requesting ProcessMaker 4 Installation Documenation

Tags: processmaker

Could you provide the brief documentation for ProcessMaker V4.0.5 Community Edition Production Installation Guide for windows?

While installing in windows there are so many issues in the local environment? I have posted in Github

https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/issues/created_by/jemiris

To avoid the issues could you provide us the installation documentation for windows users

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you install ProcessMaker 4 in a virtual machine using Linux. ProcessMaker requires a few different services that could be difficult to setup in a Windows environment (Reddit, Docker, Cron, etc). CentOS or Amazon Linux would be excellent choices. After that, follow the directions in the readme here: https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker