# How can I install ProcessMaker 4 on Windows?

Tags: processmaker

I'm new to ProcessMaker 4, I want to install it on Windows. I found a help about the installation on the web site of pm, but I want to get more help. I need a video tutorial about the installation in Win environment or a step by step help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are looking to install open Source version to test things out then refer to

Twenkid answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65548438/8560077).

However, If you are going for the enterprise edition, Your Operating system does not matter. Simply make contact with PM team and they will set up a cloud instance for you.

PM4 offers a smooth experience.

Answer (score 0):

The installation instructions for the latest version are in github:

https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker

The instructions are on Linux and the requirements include VirtualBox, it seems it's recommended on Windows to install it on a Linux virtual machine, e.g.CentOS or Amazon Linux, see the answer here:

[Requesting ProcessMaker 4 Installation Documenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711465/requesting-processmaker-4-installation-documenation)